# fileobj must implement read

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On Elastic Beanstalk I'm using the following Python code to handle a POST request and upload a file to a S3 bucket. However, I get the following error:

> fileobj must implement read

after reading Flask's FileStorage documentation, I've tried to substitute f with f.stream, but then I've got:

> expected string or buffer

I'm using Werkzeug 0.10.1. How can I fix this?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from s3upload.helpers import *

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object('s3upload.config')

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ('pdf','p')


def allowed_file(filename):
    if filename.rsplit('.')[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
        return True


def upload_file_to_s3(f, bucket_name, acl='public-read'):
    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(f, bucket_name, f.filename, ExtraArgs={
                "ACL": acl,
                "ContentType": f.content_type
            })
    except Exception as e:
        return "Something bad happened while uploading {} in {}: {} {}".format(f.filename, bucket_name, e)
    return '{}{}'.format(application.config['S3_LOCATION'], f.filename)


@application.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return "No file key in request.files"

        f = request.files['file']

        if f.filename == '':
            return "Please select a file."

        if allowed_file(f.filename):
            f.filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            out = upload_file_to_s3(f, application.config['S3_BUCKET'])
            return str(out)
        else:
            return "File type not allowed."
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Comment: Just upload the contents as `str`/`bytes`. No benefit to using `file`-like objects.